# Zeros Mat object has some values other than zero

Tags: c++, opencv

I declared a Mat object D4 with initial values zero with given dimensions and datatype.
Then to display it in smaller dimension, I wrote this

```
Mat D4=Mat::zeros(7168,7424,CV_32FC1);
Mat res6;
for (i=0; i<7168; i++)
    for(j=0; j<7424; j++)
    {
        DC_.at<uchar>(i, j) = (unsigned char)D4.at<float>(i, j);
    }
resize(DC_, res6, Size(512, 512));
imshow("Test", res6);
```

I expect a complete black image. But I get a patch of gray values on the bottom right side (that patch resembles my input image at that exact location) Why does this happen ? What is going wrong ? Please answer asap.

Comment: please show matrix creation of `DC_`? maybe it has different dimensions?

Answer (score 0):

can you please try whether the problem still occurs if you use this snippet instead?

```
 Mat D4=Mat::zeros(DC_.rows,DC_.cols,CV_32FC1);
 Mat res6;
 for (i=0; i<DC_.rows; i++)
     for(j=0; j<DC_.cols; j++)
     {
         DC_.at<uchar>(i,j) = (unsigned char)D4.at<float>(i,j);
     }
 resize(DC_,res6,Size(512,512));
 imshow("Test",res6);
```